# Search form breaks the whole page

Tags: php, css

I have found one tutorial for search form for my website. The code is working but when there is result for the search query it breaks whole page. I mean the css of site is load at half. But if there is no result from search the site is ok. 
Here is how it looks the site and the script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Searching...</title>
<link rel="icon"  type="image/x-icon"  href="media/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="include/style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">
    <?php include 'include/header.php'; ?>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="column_left">
            <?php
            $button = $_GET ['submit'];
            $search = $_GET ['search'];
            if(strlen($search)<=4)
                echo "Please enter at least 4 symbols to search";
            else{
                echo "Search terms: <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
                mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db("image");
                $search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);
                foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
                {
                    $x++;
                    if($x==1)
                        $construct .="caption LIKE '%$search_each%'";
                    else
                        $construct .="caption LIKE '%$search_each%'";
                }
                $constructs ="SELECT *, caption, alt FROM images WHERE $construct";
                $run = mysql_query($constructs);
                $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
                if ($foundnum==0)
                    echo "There is no results for:  <b>$search</b>.";
                else
                {
                    echo "Found: $foundnum results !<p>";
                    $per_page = 1;
                    $start = $_GET['start'];
                    $max_pages = ceil($foundnum / $per_page);
                    if(!$start)
                        $start=0;
                    $getquery = mysql_query("SELECT caption, name, alt FROM images WHERE $construct LIMIT $start, $per_page");
                    while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
                    {
                        echo "<img style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\" src=\"/upload/".$runrows['name']."\" /><br />";
                        echo "<h1>" . $runrows['caption'] . "</h1>";
                    }
                    $prev = $start - $per_page;
                    $next = $start + $per_page;
                    $adjacents = 3;
                    $last = $max_pages - 1;
                    if($max_pages > 1)
                    {
                        if (!($start<=0))
                            echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$prev'>Предишна</a> ";

                        if ($max_pages < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
                        {
                            $i = 0;
                            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $max_pages; $counter++)
                            {
                                if ($i == $start){
                                    echo" <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
                                }
                                $i = $i + $per_page;
                            }
                        }
                        elseif($max_pages > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
                        {
 //close to beginning; only hide later pages
                            if(($start/$per_page) < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
                            {
                                $i = 0;
                                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                                {
                                    if ($i == $start){
                                        echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
                                    }
                                    $i = $i + $per_page;
                                }
                            }
 //in middle; hide some front and some back
                            elseif($max_pages - ($adjacents * 2) > ($start / $per_page) && ($start / $per_page) > ($adjacents * 2))
                            {
                                echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=0'>1</a> ";
                                echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$per_page'>2</a> .... ";
                                $i = $start;
                                for ($counter = ($start/$per_page)+1; $counter < ($start / $per_page) + $adjacents + 2; $counter++)
                                {
                                    if ($i == $start){
                                        echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
                                    }
                                    $i = $i + $per_page;
                                }
                            }
   //close to end; only hide early pages
                            else
                            {
                                echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=0'>1</a> ";
                                echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$per_page'>2</a> .... ";
                                $i = $start;
                                for ($counter = ($start / $per_page) + 1; $counter <= $max_pages; $counter++)
                                {
                                    if ($i == $start){
                                        echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
                                    }
                                    $i = $i + $per_page;
                                }
                            }
                        }
 //next button
                        if (!($start >=$foundnum-$per_page))
                            echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&start=$next'>Следваща</a> ";
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>

            <div id="fb_com"> <script>document.write("<div class='fb-comments' data-href='" + window.location.href + "'data-num-posts='5' data-width='680'></div>");</script></div>
        </div>
        <?php include 'include/right.php'; ?>
        <br/>
        <?php include 'include/footer.php'; ?><br/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Probably some tags not being closed in the html code? For instance `echo "Found: $foundnum results !<p>";`

Comment: Ok, I fixed this. Thank's! But I can't see any other tag open.. or not closed.

Comment: if you search for one term without space does it break ? also add an echo of your query $constructs to see what's getting sent to mysql

Comment: Something doesn't work good. @zerzer, yes if is found something always break. Also it work only with latins letters .. doesn't work with Cyrillic. If I search for 'нещо' it gives me `mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Comment: what does the echo of the query `$constructs` shows you ?

Comment: So if search for `test` i get result and @construct show `caption LIKE '%test%'` but if I search for more words like `test something else` is show `mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` even if I search for terms that I know they exist in mysql and $construct doesn't echo anything..

Comment: I just found that if I search for `test` is shows me the result for every row that has this term. But if search for `test some more words` doesn't show anything.